# Cropping UIImage in two halfs

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics

I'm trying to make a method to crop my UIImages into the middle. I need to have a method that crops me the left middle of a photo, and another that crops me the right middle of another photo.

So far I have only the left part of landscape and the right of portrait:

```
if(firstImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp){   //LANDSCAPE
        UIImage *image = firstImage;
        CGImageRef tmpImgRef = image.CGImage;
        CGImageRef topImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width /2.0, image.size.height));
        firstImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImgRef];
        CGImageRelease(topImgRef);
    }
    else{      //PORTRAIT
        UIImage *image = firstImage;
        CGImageRef tmpImgRef = image.CGImage;
        CGImageRef topImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height/2.0));
        firstImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImgRef scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
        CGImageRelease(topImgRef);
    }
```

I'm not so keen on Core Graphic, can someone give me a hand? 
What I want now is to have a way to tell the `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` to crop me on **landscape** the right half instead of the left half, and on **Portrait** I need to have the left half.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but I think it could work:

```
//Portrait bottom half
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(image.width,image.height/2.0),NO,0);
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, -image.size.height/2.0) blendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy alpha:1.0];
UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Landscape right half
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(image.width/2.0,image.height),NO,0);
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-image.size.width/2.0,0) blendMode:kCGBlendModeCopy alpha:1.0];
UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```